# How can I prevent Samsung from disabling my Galaxy Note 7?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-note-7

I have a Galaxy Note 7, running on Android. How can I prevent Samsung from disabling it?

I have read in many use outlets that Galaxy Note 7 are scheduled to be disabled, e.g. [Samsung May Permanently Disable Galaxy Note 7 Phones In The US As Soon As Next Week](https://mobile.slashdot.org/story/16/12/09/0123228/samsung-may-permanently-disable-galaxy-note-7-phones-in-the-us-as-soon-as-next-week):

> As of December 15th, Samsung will modify the software to prevent the Galaxy Note 7 from charging. The phone will no longer work.

Comment: I don't have one, but wouldn't disabling updates take care for that? Or rooting and installing a custom ROM? ;)

Comment: Simply by disabling automatic update in settings > about device. Since it is said Samsung would release an update in the United States to disable the Galaxy Note 7 completely. According to this http://www.sammobile.com/2016/12/09/galaxy-note-7-will-be-disabled-via-update-in-the-us-on-december-19/

Comment: I used to have a Samsung Galaxy S5, where Android automatically got upgraded after I had ignored the [upgrade request](http://i.stack.imgur.com/bY6nT.png) several times (and I had turned off the automatic upgrades). So I am quite concerned regarding my Galaxy Note 7, and was looking for some more robust way to make any OS upgrade impossible.

Comment: I don't understand this question. It is clear the company, and all supporting systems to the system are being ground down to nothing. Like an apple on a branch with no supporting tree. How do you plan to survive, and, most importantly, why?

Comment: @wbogacz I am happy with my current phone.